# Regex with dutch phone numbers

Tags: java, regex, phone-number

I need to create a regex for dutch phone numbers. What I got so far:

```
[0-9\\-\\+]{8,14}
```

That regex works perfectly for normal numbers such as: 020-5951611

However I need to add service numbers such as "112", "0800-1234" but "0909-12345678" has to be invalid because it's too long.
I've got a file with a lot of test cases (down here), if there's true the number should be valid, if it's false the number is not valid.

```
    System.err.println("running checkNummer");
    TelefoonNummerChecker instance = new TelefoonNummerChecker();
    assertEquals(true, instance.checkNummer("020-5951611"));
    assertEquals(true, instance.checkNummer("0205951611"));
    assertEquals(true, instance.checkNummer("+31205951611"));
    assertEquals(true, instance.checkNummer("+3120-5951611"));
    assertEquals(true, instance.checkNummer("+31612345678"));
    assertEquals(true, instance.checkNummer("+316-12345678"));
    assertEquals(true, instance.checkNummer("06-12345678"));
    assertEquals(true, instance.checkNummer("0612345678"));
    assertEquals(true, instance.checkNummer("0031612345678"));
    assertEquals(true, instance.checkNummer("00316-12345678"));
    assertEquals(true, instance.checkNummer("0234-123456"));
    assertEquals(true, instance.checkNummer("0234123456"));
    assertEquals(true, instance.checkNummer("+31234-123456"));
    assertEquals(true, instance.checkNummer("+31234123456"));
    assertEquals(true, instance.checkNummer("+31320123456")); // lelystad 0320
    assertEquals(true, instance.checkNummer("0031320123456"));
    assertEquals(true, instance.checkNummer("0031320-123456"));
    assertEquals(true, instance.checkNummer("0320-123456"));
    // korte service nummers:
    assertEquals(true, instance.checkNummer("112")); 
    assertEquals(true, instance.checkNummer("0800-1234")); 
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("0909-12345678")); // too long
    assertEquals(true, instance.checkNummer("09001234")); 
    assertEquals(true, instance.checkNummer("08009876")); 
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("0808-123456"));
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("+32205951611")); // not valid in NL
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("+3220-5951611")); // not valid in NL
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("02-05951611")); // before dash should be 3 or 4 long
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("02-15951611")); // before dash should be 3 or 4 long
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("0-215951611")); // before dash should be 3 or 4 long
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("02059-51611")); // before dash should be 3 or 4 long
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("0034-1234567")); // before dash may not have 2x a 0
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("0200951611"));   // may not start with 0
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("02059516229")); // too long
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("020595162")); // too short
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("020-0234567")); // may not start with 0
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("123456789"));   // no 10 numbers
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("1234567890"));   // net number doesn't start with 0
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("123-5951619")); // net number doesn't start with 0
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("0320-012345")); // abo starts with zero

    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("+31-205951611")); // no dash before abon number
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("+31-2-05951611")); // no 2x -
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("+31-2-0-5951611")); // no 2x -
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("+31-2-0-595161-1")); // no 2x -
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("06-1-2345678")); // no 2x -
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("020-59-51611")); // no 2x -
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("020-5-9-51611")); // no 2x -
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("0205951-611")); // too long
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("06-1-2345678")); // no 2x -
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("0045106539985")); // not dutch
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("0031476534")); // 0031, not enough numbers next to 0031
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("+310612345678")); // 06 must be 6
    assertEquals(false, instance.checkNummer("00310205951688")); // 020 must be 20
    System.err.println("end test checkNummer");
```

I hope someone could help me with this, thanks in advance!

Edit: It should be in Java.

Comment: validating phone number form with regex shares the same pitfalls as validating emails with regex. Can you catch everything? Is it worth it? What are you trying to validate - existing numbers or the number the user intended? If the latter, consider a 'confirm number' input. Is failing a problem that the users experience often? Would a verfication procedure be more useful?

Comment: Another similar question has been [asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949757/regular-expression-for-dutch-phone-number). Try the solutions there and see if it satisfies your needs. On another note, you don't need to escape `+` in a character class since it will lose it's meaning, put `-` at the end of the character class and it won't form a range which means it also loses it's meaning. Congratulation, you just saved 4 bytes and a pain to the eyes `[0-9+-]{8,14}`

Comment: Could you perhaps put english comments in your code snippet please?

Comment: @Jerry, I'm updating it right now.

Comment: Why is `06-12345678` valid but `02-15951611` invalid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I once wrote a phonenumber regex in python that matches international phone numbers but has special support for Dutch phone numbers. Maybe this can help you create your own regex.

If you want to run this snippet, note that this function uses the python [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/0.1.20120506) module that you should install in order to use it.

```
import regex


def phone_regex():
    """
    Matches phone numbers with formatting like spaces, parentheses and
    dashes.

    Has special checkig for dutch phone numbers, but supports international
    phone numbers too.

    more info:
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_international_call_prefixes
    https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telefoonnummer
    https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informatienummer
    """

    # a number with possibly a dash prepended
    num_dash = '(?:-\s*)?[0-9]\s*'

    return regex.compile(r'''
        ^(?:

        \s*

            # Dutch phone number:

                (?:

                    #regular numbers:

                        (?:
                            # a zero followed by a a nonzero number
                            0\s*[1-9]\s*
                            (?:''' + num_dash + '''){8}
                        |
                            # 3 digit area code in parentheses
                            \(0\s*[1-9]\s*[0-9]\s*\)\s*
                            (?:''' + num_dash + '''){7}
                        |
                            # 4 digit area code in parentheses
                            \(0\s*[1-9]\s*(?:[0-9]\s*){2}\)\s*
                            (?:''' + num_dash + '''){6}
                        )

                |

                    # infonumbers:

                        (?:
                            # 0900 number
                            0\s*9\s*0\s*0\s*
                        |
                            # 0800 number
                            0\s*8\s*0\s*0\s*
                        |
                            # 0906 number
                            0\s*9\s*0\s*6\s*
                        |
                            # 0909 number
                            0\s*9\s*0\s*9\s*
                        )
                        (?:''' + num_dash + '''){4,7}

                |

                    # 112 alarm number
                    1\s*1\s*2\s*

                )

        |

            # International phone number:

                # plus sign, to indicate international phone number
                \+\s*
                # the country code, can be 1 to 4 characters
                (?:[0-9]\s*){1,4}

                # area code, can be a number from 1 to 4 digits
                (?:
                    # area code in parentheses
                    \((?:[0-9]\s*){1,4}\)\s*
                |
                    # area code without parentheses
                    (?:[0-9]\s*){1,4}
                )

                # local number
                (?:''' + num_dash + '''){5,9}

        )$''', regex.X)
```

Comment: I think the user is using Java though.

Comment: I think this question is more about the regex than the language ;)

Comment: Well, I guess, if the user understands how strings are handled in python. Putting it [here](http://regex101.com/r/lS3pL0) doesn't seem to work for the sample numbers though.

Comment: Ok man, next time i'll just shut up and don't share any helpful information. Thank you too.

Comment: I didn't mean to sound offensive. I was just mentioning it so that you could try fix it before OP tries it.

Comment: I'm just submitting this code to help you. To customize the regex to your needs specifically would take some time. Does everybody on Stack Overflow expect we all take an hour off just to provide someone with a ready-made regex?

Comment: If this helps you write your own regex you can always submit your own regex as an answer to your own question and mark that one as the correct answer. I'd be happy to have helped you. That's what we're here for in the end aren't we.