# PHP code with regexp for dutch phone are not working

Tags: php, regex

I actually used the expression from the solution given in [Regular expression for Dutch phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949757/regular-expression-for-dutch-phone-number) for my php code below, but this code is not working.

The code is simple but I don't see where I go wrong ?

```
define("REGEXP_PHONE_NL","(^\+[0-9]{2}|^\+[0-9]{2}\(0\)|^\(\+[0-9]{2}\)\(0\)|^00[0-9]{2}|^0)([0-9]{9}$|[0-9\-\s]{10}$)");

$string = "+31123456789"; //based on solution given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949757/regular-expression-for-dutch-phone-number

echo(filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,array("options"=>array("regexp"=>REGEXP_PHONE_NL))));
```

Comment: How does "not working" present itself exactly? What is the input, what the outpur and what is the desired output? Also your `$string` does not match the dutch phone number pattern since it is not followed by 9 numbers but by 10 due to the `6` behind the `+31`.

Comment: filter_var() returns false based on the given $string value ("+316123456789") - instead of the expected return value "+316123456789". Possible desired outputs: "Regular expression to evaluate dutch-style phone numbers. Possible example prefixes: +31, +31(0), (+31)(0), 0, 0031 followed by 9 numbers (which can contain a space or -)"

Comment: the regex works thou. tested it at http://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex itself works, but you forgot to put same characters in the beginning and in the end of the pattern (delimeters).

```
<?php
    define("REGEXP_PHONE_NL","/(^\+[0-9]{2}|^\+[0-9]{2}\(0\)|^\(\+[0-9]{2}\)\(0\)|^00[0-9]{2}|^0)([0-9]{9}$|[0-9\-\s]{10}$)/");
    $string = "+316123456789"; //based on solution given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949757/regular-expression-for-dutch-phone-number
    var_dump(filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,array("options"=>array("regexp"=>REGEXP_PHONE_NL))));
```

See it working [here](http://ideone.com/SjRSOp).

Answer (score 0):

You are **missing** to put **regexp identifier** character **forward slash (/)** in your regular expression pattern i add forward slash before and after,

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo code Viper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7b4f6G)**</kbd>

#### PHP

```
<?php
define("REGEXP_PHONE_NL","/(^\+[0-9]{2}|^\+[0-9]{2}\(0\)|^\(\+[0-9]{2}\)\(0\)|^00[0-9]{2}|^0)([0-9]{9}$|[0-9\-\s]{10}$)/");

$string = "+316123456789"; //based on solution given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949757/regular-expression-for-dutch-phone-number

echo filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,array("options"=>array("regexp"=>REGEXP_PHONE_NL)));

?>
```

#### Result

```
+316123456789
```