# Regular expression dutch mobile number or international number

Tags: regex

I use a regular expression to validate a Dutch mobile phone number:

`^((\+316|06|00316){1}\\s?-?\s?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7})$`

So the number should start with 06 or +316 or 00316 followed by 8 digits (not starting with a 0)

Now I have to extend the validation so it also allows for international numbers from outside The Netherlands.

I want to keep it simple so I was thinking:

If it not starts with 06 or +316 or 00316 then it should start with '00dd' or '+dd' where dd!=31 followed by 8 till 12 digits.

so 0032127384562 should match but 00317198765432 not (because it starts with 0031 but not 00316)

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Even the 8-12 digits of the international number cannot start with 0?

Comment: can you process the data twice by making a separate regex for international?

Comment: I've just shared an answer here for Dutch mobile numbers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46280603/4385010

Answer (score 0):

The regex for the international number is:

```
^00(?!31)[0-9]{2}\s?-?\s?[1-9][0-9]{7,11}$
```

or, if you can't use lookahead:

```
^00([0-24-9][0-9]|3[02-9])\s?-?\s?[1-9][0-9]{7,11}$
```

You can concatenate it with `|` and the Dutch regex.

Be aware that there is a typo in your regex at `\\`.